# How to test the obfuscated(Proguard) jar file in Android project?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I have developed an Android project. I want to protect my code from reverse engineering, so i made a .jar file which contains all my class files then obfuscate that .jar file using the tool "Proguard GUI". Proguard obfuscate the .jar file perfectly, Now how can i use and test the obfuscated jar file in my project?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "test the obfuscated jar". Just use a Java decompiler of your choice and open the files. You will see that for example class names or methods are obfuscated, replaced or whatever, depending on your ProGuard settings.

Comment: @Bevor The class files are obfuscated successfully. Now i wanna use those obfuscated class files in my android project and build a .apk. I don't know it is possible or not?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works in this way. Usually these tasks like (obfuscation, signing, zipaligning,...) should be processed in your gradle file.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for  your valuable answer. I will try to obfuscate by Android studio gradle file. If you know any tutorials or web references for Proguard, Please send me the link.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672409/how-to-configure-proguard-using-gradle

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bevor I have configured proguard in build gradle and obfuscated the project. Its working fine.